# LDAP: error code 67 - Not Allowed On RDN

Tags: ldap

I'm trying to import the following `LDIF` into `Tivoli Directory Server` ..

```
dn: dc=root,dc=ibm,dc=com
objectclass: domain
objectclass: top
dc: dc=root,dc=ibm,dc=com

dn: cn=users,dc=root,dc=ibm,dc=com
objectclass: domain
objectclass: top
dc: cn=users,dc=root,dc=ibm,dc=com
```

I get this warning .. `According to the schema attribute CN is not allowed`

Followed by an error .. `LDAP: error code 67 - Not Allowed On RDN`

I'm following some `IBM` documentation , so not sure where I'm going wrong?

http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSZLC2_7.0.0/com.ibm.commerce.admin.doc/tasks/tmswmmdirserver.htm

Comment: This site is for programming questions. We are not general software/server tech support.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Went with this ..

```
dn: dc=root,dc=ibm,dc=com
objectclass: domain
objectclass: top
dc: dc=root,dc=ibm,dc=com

dn: cn=users,dc=root,dc=ibm,dc=com
objectclass: container
objectclass: top
cn: cn=users,dc=root,dc=ibm,dc=com
```

Answer (score 0):

The `objectclass` `domain` does not allow the `cn` attribute according to your current schema (neither does `top` which is the mother of all `objectlass`es). Try `dn: dc=users,dc=root,dc=ibm,dc=com` instead because the `dc` attribute is available on `domain` entries.